# Tangent half angle subsititution (Integration Query)

Tags: calculus

How would you go about solving something like $$\int \frac{1}{4+5\cos{t}}~dt$$

I am aware that you would use a substitution involving the half angle of tan but I am unsure on how to apply it.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is also known as [Weierstrass Substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution).

This is done by substituting $u=\tan\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)$. We must derive formulae in terms of $u$ for $\cos{t}$ and $dt$. The substitutions are rather standard, but I will derive them for you:

---

For $\cos{t}$, we use the identity:
$$\cos{\theta}\equiv 1-2\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) \tag{1}$$
Applying it gives:
$$\cos{t}= 1-2\sin^2\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)=1-\frac{2\tan^2\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}{\sec^2\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}$$
Now, we use the following identity on $\sec^2\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)$:
$$\tan^2{\theta}+1\equiv\sec^2{\theta} \tag{2}$$
This gives:
$$\cos{t}=1-\frac{2u^2}{u^2+1}$$
Hence:
$$\boxed{\cos{t}=\frac{1-u^2}{u^2+1}}$$

---

Now, for $dt$, we first evaluate the derivative of $u$ with respect to $t$:
$$\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{1}{2}\sec^2\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)$$
Using the identity in $(2)$, we obtain:
$$\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{1}{2}(u^2+1)$$
Hence:
$$\boxed{dt=\frac{2}{u^2+1}~du}$$

---

After substitution, we obtain:
$$\int \frac{1}{4+5\cos{t}}~dt=\int \frac{1}{4+5\left(\frac{1-u^2}{u^2+1}\right)}\cdot \frac{2}{u^2+1}~du=\int \frac{2}{9-u^2}~du$$
Can you continue?

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot mate

Answer (score 0):

use the substitution $$t=\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$ and $$\cos(x)={\frac {1- \left( \tan \left( t/2 \right)  \right) ^{2}}{1+ \left( 
\tan \left( t/2 \right)  \right) ^{2}}}
$$